# What is behind experimental function: FindFormula?

Tags: fitting, implementation-details, machine-learning

In version [10.2](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn102.html) there is a new experimental function: [`FindFormula[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html).

I suspect that a [genetic programming algorithm (symbolic regression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_regression) is behind this new feature, but I can't find any references.

**Question**

- What is behind this new function?

Comment: It was inevitable that someone would come along and ask this…

Comment: FWIW I used [**this**](http://www.nutonian.com/products/eureqa/) until it became paid

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: The thing is that I have been working in this area for quite some time and I was quite delighted when I saw this new feature.

Comment: @belisarius: Yeah, this is quite a good program!

Comment: Another question is whether this can be used in WolframAlpha (Pro)? I didn't find it there.

Comment: Quite unlikely; I haven't ever seen them add functions to Alpha at the same time as in a new version of *Mathematica*.

Comment: I think it builds Ill-formed questions from a cursory scan, posts them here, scrapes any answers, and returns the result.... :-)

Comment: @belisarius Let me guess... now Eureqa costs an arm and a leg in individual use? It's never a great sign when you have trouble finding pricing from a seemingly simple web site.

Comment: @kirma It was free for many years while they were developing the product. It is (was) an incredible piece of software. I threw in clouds of (almost ) nonsensical points and received back unbelievable correlations. Now they aim high an sell a mixture of product and cloud (sounds familiar?) to fortune 500 and big labs.  A pity. No "individual" license the last time I checked

Comment: @belisarius: I even helped them in the start-up phase and received an academic license. This has expired now and I emailed them to renew it - no answer so far. I am really disappointed.

Comment: @vonjd Hope you'll get it! There shouldn't be _that_   difficult to be generous

Comment: This  [related product](http://www.sigmaplot.com/products/tablecurve2d/tablecurve2d.php) does a search over 3665 buil-in equations and returns the best

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Experimental function `FindFormula[]` at the moment is using a combination of different methods: it combines non linear regression with Markov chain Monte Carlo methods (e.g. Metropolis–Hastings algorithm). In the future (possibly in V$10.3$) there will be an option allowing the user to choose which method to use.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!

Comment: Thank you. How do you know that? Are you in the development team?

Comment: Just found this post. Interesting, Monte Carlo seems to be involved. I have a set of data (not very large, 121 data points) which delivers distinct results every time FindFormula is invoked. I first thought of a bug, but now I see it´s a feature ;-)

Answer (score 9):

I doubt that this is very robust. Consider a simple change in the DE example in the Documentation:

```
sol = y /. NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x], y[0] == 2}, y, {x, -5, 300}][[1]];
times = N[Range[-5, 600]/9];
data = Transpose[{times, sol[times] + RandomReal[0.05, Length[times]]}];
lp = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

Now

```
FindFormula[data, x, 1, TargetFunctions -> {Exp, Sin, Cos}]
```

thinks the best solution is `2.27414 Sin[x] + 2.5479`. Whereas a *much better* solution, obviously compatible with the selected **TargetFunctions**, is `2 Exp[Sin[x]]`.

Comment: On the other hand, is `FindFormula[]` even smart enough to consider composing `TargetFunctions`?

Comment: You don't need to change the DE to get this.  The behaviour is the same with the original.  Every time I run it I get a different result, and that result is *sometimes* $e^{\sin{x}}$.  The same with the modified one: put it in a `Table[..., {20}]` and very likely at least one of the results will be $2 e^{\sin x}$.  (But requesting 20 functions within the `FindFormula` doesn't work nearly as well.)

Answer (score 8):

The following reveals definitions

```
<< GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions@FindFormula
```

As usual one can click the symbols to find definitions of functions "further down". It should also be noted that `FindFormula` is listed in the [Machine Learning guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MachineLearning.html), which corresponds to symbol names like `` SymbolicMachineLearning`PackageScope`ImputArgumentsTestFindFormula `` shown further down by `PrintDefinitions`.