# How to fit a data set in an iterative way?

Tags: fitting

I am going to fit a data set in the following way.
I have a data set $y$ vs. $x$. $y$ is again a function of $t$ i.e. $y=f(t)$. With varying $t$, I can get different $y$ and can plot $y$ vs. $x$, and fit each plot to find the fitting parameters. I need all the fitting parameters with varying $t$.
I have used code like this:

```
dataf = Table[FindFit[data, a + b*i, {a, b}, i], {i, 1, 5}]
```

This does not work. I don't understand how to express it? 
Please help.

Comment: Hi Partha. It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve there. Could you please provide an example data set for `data`? Do you mean that your model looks like `y[[i]] = f(x[[i]],t)` with lists `x` and `y` prescribed and `t` being a further parameter?

Comment: Err... sorry for using incorrect syntax. I meant $y_i = f(x_i,t)$ (or `y[[i]] == f[x[[i]], t]`).

Comment: You have `i` serving two different roles here. You're telling `FindFit` that it's the independent variable in the fitting formula, but then you're trying to use it as a `Table` index, too. I can't understand what you're attempting.

Comment: My entire equation looks like: fit = Table[
  FindFit[Transpose[{\[Nu], (NormalisedIntensity/
        avglifetime)*(\[Tau][[1]]*Exp[-t/\[Tau][[2]]] + \[Tau][[3]]*
         Exp[-t/\[Tau][[4]]] + \[Tau][[5]]*Exp[-t/\[Tau][[6]]])}], 
   h*Exp[ -(0.693)*(  Log[1 + 2*a*(\[Nu] - n)/d]/a )^2] , {a, d, n, 
    h}, t], {t, 0, 2}]

Comment: I have a data having function like y[[i]]=f[x[[i]],t]. I want to find the fitted parameters for a fixed value of t. then changing t I can get the another fitted parameters. I need all the fitted parameters with t to plot a time dependent slope.

Comment: this may be useful: [Curve fitting by running through hundreds of models and return the one with best fit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65757/125)

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = {#, #^2 RandomReal[{.9, 1.1}]} & /@ Range[100];
f[x_, t_] := a + b x^t;

fitf[t_] := FindFit[data, f[x, t], {a, b}, x]
fittedmodels = Table[With[{t = t}, Evaluate[f[x, t] /. fitf[t]]], {t, 1, 5}];
Show[Plot[Evaluate@fittedmodels, {x, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Thick,  
   PlotLegends -> ("t = " <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[5])], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]]
```

[image]