# How to fit polynomial curve using Mathematica for multiple inputs?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, functions, polynomials

I am new to mathematica. I have 3 inputs and 1 output. I want to find the 'N' th degree of polynomial which would approimately fit my dataset. I tried FindFit but it does not solve my problem. I also tried Neural Networks but want to do Polynomial Curve Fitting. I want to predict what degree of polynomial would fit to my data as the relation is Non-Linear(i.e. F(A)+F(B)+F(C) =Output)

Basically I want to find the 'n' degree polynomial which would approximate my data.

```
{{"A", "B", "C", "Output"}, {57.0088, 76.2105, 46.4823, 
  46.8503}, {56.2162, 75.5021, 44.8855, 47.1508}, {57.189, 74.434, 
  44.8579, 48.4662}, {57.551, 75.3068, 46.6976, 45.9044}, {55.9446, 
  75.4585, 47.2454, 46.3321}, {58.7154, 76.9871, 47.2429, 
  50.8479}, {59.7091, 79.1212, 48.5647, 50.7675}, {59.5948, 78.0647, 
  47.5596, 48.7605}, {59.9859, 77.9062, 50.9319, 48.0986}, {60.5902, 
  78.1553, 54.5241, 51.1845}, {59.6509, 77.6456, 53.0787, 
  52.9824}, {62.7154, 74.9587, 53.5889, 52.242}, {62.8849, 81.0653, 
  55.2839, 50.2263}, {63.2489, 78.4848, 54.355, 51.0166}, {64.6259, 
  78.9331, 54.9457, 53.4716}, {65.4176, 79.1202, 55.1678, 
  53.1001}, {64.962, 77.6563, 54.3707, 53.6528}, {63.8401, 79.6976, 
  51.0827, 54.067}, {64.4447, 82.2205, 52.9363, 55.5474}, {64.7958, 
  82.149, 55.1345, 57.0765}}
```

[image: Poly]

Comment: Acually they are not a mesh, it is weight in (Kg), where the output is a physically measured one. and A,B,C are other weight functions affecting the output. So how to fit polynomial curve to the data?

Comment: Please ad links between this and the cross-post on Wolfram Community.

Comment: A quibble about terminology:  A linear model is "linear" in the parameters rather than "linear" in the predictors.  So a polynomial is a linear model and polynomials can be fit with `LinearModelFit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modifying the approach from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65761/125):

```
vars = {x, y, z};
maxdegree = 3;
cols = Join @@ (MonomialList[(Plus @@ vars)^#] /. _Integer x_ :> x & /@ Range[0, maxdegree])
```

> {1, x, y, z, x^2, x y, x z, y^2, y z, z^2, x^3, x^2 y, x^2 z, x y^2, 
>    x y z, x z^2, y^3, y^2 z, y z^2, z^3}

Specify the maximum number of terms (`nparams`) including the intercept (`1`)  and construct all possible models with up to `nparams` terms

```
nparams = 6;
models = Subsets[cols, {1, nparams}];
Length @ models
```

> 60459

Use `LinearModelFit` for each model with the option `IncludeConstantBasis -> False`:

```
fits = Table[Join[{j}, {Length @ j}, 
    LinearModelFit[data, j, vars, IncludeConstantBasis -> False][
      {"BestFit", "AICc", "BIC", "AdjustedRSquared", "RSquared"}]], 
   {j, models}];
```

Take the top 20 (say) by [`"AICc"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#AICc) and display:

```
topTwentyByAICc = SortBy[fits, #[[4]] &][[;; 20]];
Style[# /. x_Real :> Round[x, .00001]] &@
 Grid[{{"Model", "Length", "BestFit", "AICc", "BIC", 
    "AdjustedRSquared", "RSquared"}, ## & @@ topTwentyByAICc}, 
  Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**Note:** As JimB noted in comments, when the model does not include a constant bases (1 is not the basis) R^2 and AdjustedR^2 are meaningless.

Comment: In the `SortBy` command you don't want the minus sign if front of `#[[4]]`.  (`AICc` has the log likelihood multiplied already by -1 so low values indicate better models.)  You've produced the bottom 20 models rather than the top 20 models.

Comment: And while I'm being picky, $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$ are nonsensical (or at best misleading) when the intercept is forced to be zero (`IncludeConstantBasis -> False`).

Comment: @JimB, great points , thank you!  I fixed the table and added a note re R^2 when the  model does not contain an intercept term.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a final analysis but just to get you started, let's look at the data

```
data = {{57.0088, 76.2105, 46.4823, 46.8503}, {56.2162, 75.5021, 
         44.8855, 47.1508}, {57.189, 74.434, 44.8579, 48.4662}, {57.551, 
         75.3068, 46.6976, 45.9044}, {55.9446, 75.4585, 47.2454, 
         46.3321}, {58.7154, 76.9871, 47.2429, 50.8479}, {59.7091, 79.1212, 
         48.5647, 50.7675}, {59.5948, 78.0647, 47.5596, 48.7605}, {59.9859, 
         77.9062, 50.9319, 48.0986}, {60.5902, 78.1553, 54.5241, 
         51.1845}, {59.6509, 77.6456, 53.0787, 52.9824}, {62.7154, 74.9587, 
         53.5889, 52.242}, {62.8849, 81.0653, 55.2839, 50.2263}, {63.2489, 
         78.4848, 54.355, 51.0166}, {64.6259, 78.9331, 54.9457, 
         53.4716}, {65.4176, 79.1202, 55.1678, 53.1001}, {64.962, 77.6563, 
         54.3707, 53.6528}, {63.8401, 79.6976, 51.0827, 54.067}, {64.4447, 
         82.2205, 52.9363, 55.5474}, {64.7958, 82.149, 55.1345, 57.0765}}
```

via `ListDensityPlot3D`

```
p1 = ListDensityPlot3D[data, AxesLabel -> {"A", "B", "C"}]
```

[image: ListDensityPlot3D]

Ok, this looks like it might be approximated sufficiently by a linear gradient. We can get a fit via `LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit` (also `Fit` and `FindFit` but they are not as versatile). Let's use `NonlinearModelFit` in case we want to extend the model to something more complicated later:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[
        data,
        w[1] a + w[2] b + w[3] c + w[4],
        {w[1], w[2], w[3], w[4]},
        {a, b, c}
      ]
```

> FittedModel[-14.9611+0.730883 a+0.294494 b-0.0325676 c]

and plot it in the same way

```
p2 = DensityPlot3D[
       fit[a, b, c],
       {a, 55, 66}, {b, 74, 83}, {c, 44, 56}, 
       PlotRange -> AbsoluteOptions[p1, PlotRange][[1, 2]], 
       AxesLabel -> {"A", "B", "C"}
     ]
```

[image: DensityPlot3D of fit]

We can use the `ConvexHullMesh` of the data points to create a `RegionMember` function to plot our fit in the same region as we got earlier with `ListDensityPlot3D`:

```
rm = RegionMember[ConvexHullMesh[data[[All, ;; 3]]]]
rmn[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, f_] := rm[{x, y, z}]
p3 = DensityPlot3D[
       fit[a, b, c], {a, 55, 66}, {b, 74, 83}, {c, 44, 56}, 
       PlotRange -> AbsoluteOptions[p1, PlotRange][[1, 2]], 
       AxesLabel -> {"A", "B", "C"},
       RegionFunction -> rmn
     ]
```

[image: DensityPlot3D of fit confined to same region as original data domain]

From here we could go into different directions (more complicated model, verifying the quality of the fit, etc.), but this might be a start!

Answer (score 2):

Polynomial Fit (data as defined in @Thies Heidecke 's answer)

```
fit[x_, y_, z_] :=Fit[data, 
{1, x, y, z, x^2, x y, y^2, x z, y z, z^2, x^3, x^2 y,x y^2, y^3, x^2 z, x y z, y^2 z, x z^2, y z^2, z^3} (* polynomial basis *)
, {x, y, z}] //Evaluate
```

fits the data very well

```
Map[#[[-1]] - Apply[fit, Most[#]] &, data]
(* O[10^-10] *)
```

Comment: Or take the [`Norm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) of your result: `Norm@((#[[-1]] - fit @@ (Most@#)) & /@ data)`

Answer (score 2):

Following [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94154/10397), we can find fit with minimal [*Akaike Information Criterion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) ( *AIC* ) by calculating a series of fits with 1, 2, ...`maxn` fits, and selecting the fit with the smallest "*AIC*" as defined in the [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) documentation.

```
kvar[n_]:={x^n,y^n,z^n};
kvar[0]=1;
kpar[n_]:={a[n],b[n],c[n]};
kpar[0]=d[0];
gmodel[n_Integer]:=kpar[0]+Sum[kvar[i].kpar[i],{i,1,n}];
gpars[n_Integer]:=Flatten@Array[kpar,n+1,{0,n}]
fitg[data_,maxn_Integer]:=MinimalBy[Table[{#,#["AIC"]}&@NonlinearModelFit[data,gmodel[n],gpars[n],{x,y,z}],{n,maxn}],Last][[1,1]]
```

The data

```
dat={{57.0088,76.2105,46.4823,46.8503},{56.2162,75.5021,44.8855,47.1508},{57.189,74.434,44.8579,48.4662},{57.551,75.3068,46.6976,45.9044},{55.9446,75.4585,47.2454,46.3321},{58.7154,76.9871,47.2429,50.8479},{59.7091,79.1212,48.5647,50.7675},{59.5948,78.0647,47.5596,48.7605},{59.9859,77.9062,50.9319,48.0986},{60.5902,78.1553,54.5241,51.1845},{59.6509,77.6456,53.0787,52.9824},{62.7154,74.9587,53.5889,52.242},{62.8849,81.0653,55.2839,50.2263},{63.2489,78.4848,54.355,51.0166},{64.6259,78.9331,54.9457,53.4716},{65.4176,79.1202,55.1678,53.1001},{64.962,77.6563,54.3707,53.6528},{63.8401,79.6976,51.0827,54.067},{64.4447,82.2205,52.9363,55.5474},{64.7958,82.149,55.1345,57.0765}};
```

Noy we try fits up to order 10.

```
Quiet@fitg[dat,10]
(* FittedModel[-14.9611+0.730883 x+0.294494 y-0.0325676 z] *)
```

And we find the best fit is linear.