# Fitting two-dimensional data

Tags: fitting, interpolation, data

For this question, I cannot use random sample data. So the actual data can be found [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/4hjs2rzch5dz3oo/L1.dat/file). The data file contains three columns, where the first two are the coordinates $(x,y)$, while the third is the value of a function $f$. Now we plot them, thus obtaining the shape of $f$

```
data = Import["L1.dat", "Table"];
```

or

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/YMCFB4mK", "TSV"]
```

Plot

```
L0 = ListPlot3D[data]
```

[image]

My question is the following: is there a way to interpolate the data and obtain an analytical fitting function $f(x,y)$? Taking into account that the distribution of $f$ is rather smooth, without peaks and holes, I suppose it should be rather easy to obtain its fitting function. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `Interpolation`? E.g., `iF = Interpolation[data];Plot3D[iF[x, y], {x, 0, .5}, {y, 0, 1}]`?

Comment: @kglr I want to obtain an analytical equation of the form f = ax^2 + b*y^2 +....

Comment: It's either `Interpolation` or fit. What is it?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all timezones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers. I have edited my answer so you can accept the best one later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Interpolation

```
intFunc = With[
  {
   order = 1,
   dat = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/YMCFB4mK", "TSV"]
   },
  Interpolation[{{#1, #2}, #3} & @@@ dat, InterpolationOrder -> order]
  ]

Plot3D[
 intFunc[x, y]
 , {x, 0.001, 1/2}
 , {y, 0, 1}
 , PlotStyle -> Green
 ]
```

[image]

### Fit

```
fitModel = With[
  {
   order = 4,
   dat = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/YMCFB4mK", "TSV"]
   },
  LinearModelFit[
   dat
   , Flatten@Outer[Times, Sequence @@ Transpose@Array[Power[{x, y}, # - 1] &, order + 1]]
   , {x, y}
   ]
  ]

fitModel[x,y]
(* 0.839678 - 3.39587 x + 10.2762 x^2 - 23.2243 x^3 + 18.9954 x^4 - 
 0.870772 y - 1.85421 x y + 14.7251 x^2 y - 36.8365 x^3 y + 
 31.9079 x^4 y + 1.78944 y^2 + 5.55233 x y^2 - 43.8506 x^2 y^2 + 
 111.182 x^3 y^2 - 96.807 x^4 y^2 - 1.99269 y^3 - 5.49884 x y^3 + 
 46.2492 x^2 y^3 - 118.606 x^3 y^3 + 103.764 x^4 y^3 + 0.819593 y^4 + 
 1.98819 x y^4 - 17.6815 x^2 y^4 + 45.7184 x^3 y^4 - 40.1317 x^4 y^4 *)

Show[
 Plot3D[
  fitModel[x, y]
  , {x, 0, 1/2}
  , {y, 0, 1}
  , PlotStyle -> Blue
  ]
 , ListPlot3D[
  dat
  , PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.5]]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I think you misunderstand the output of `LinearModelFit`. The fit is linear only on the coefficients. See my edit.

Answer (score 5):

Adapting the approach from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201554/125):

```
vars = {x, y};
maxdegree = 3;
cols = Join @@ (MonomialList[(Plus @@ vars)^#] /. _Integer x_ :> x & /@ Range[maxdegree]);
nparams = 5;
models = Prepend[#, 1] & /@ Subsets[cols, {1, nparams}];
Length@models
```

> 381

```
fits = Table[Join[{j}, {Length@j}, LinearModelFit[l1dat, j, vars][{"BestFit", "AICc", "BIC", 
     "AdjustedRSquared", "RSquared"}]], {j, models}]

topTenByAICc = SortBy[fits, #[[4]] &][[;; 10]];
Style[# /. x_Real :> Round[x, .00001]] &@
 Grid[{{"Model", "Length", "BestFit", "AICc", "BIC", 
    "AdjustedRSquared", "RSquared"}, ## & @@ topTenByAICc}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
bestmodel = topTenByAICc[[1, 3]];
Show[Plot3D[bestmodel, {x, 0, .6}, {y, 0, .1}, Mesh -> None], 
 ListPointPlot3D[l1dat, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, Red]]]
```

[image]